# Validate field data in a file and replace with integer

Tags: bash, shell

I have below data in a file. As you see in some rows 5th filed having some integer number like 100, 300 etc and some rows 5th field contains string value as "value". I want 5th field in any row does not contain integer number to be replaced with '=100'.

```
domain=server=hgdndh=0=100=value
domain=server=mds-hnfgd=0=200=value
domain=server=fjghgn=0=value
domain=server=skrufh=0=value
domain=server=kfhgnvb=0=value
domain=server=jghfnf=0=value
domain=server=fhf-ejeu-fkgj=0=100=value
domain=server=fhdnd=0=300=value
```

Below is the output which I am looking for:

```
domain=server=hgdndh=0=100=value
domain=server=mds-hnfgd=0=200=value
domain=server=fjghgn=0=100=value
domain=server=skrufh=0=100=value
domain=server=kfhgnvb=0=100=value
domain=server=jghfnf=0=100=value
domain=server=fhf-ejeu-fkgj=0=100=value
domain=server=fhdnd=0=300=value
```

With below piece of code I get the those particulars rows where file is having string at 5th field but can you please help me to replace that string and get the above output.

```
while read -r line
do
line_a=$(echo $line|awk -F"=" '{print $5}')
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $line_a =~ $re ]] ; then
echo "Not a string"
fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- data does not contain the delimiter (`=`)
- all records have 5 or 6 `=`-delimited fields
- for records with 5 fields we want to keep the last/5th field (eg, `value` in the sample data)
- for records with 5 fields we want to insert a new field (eg, `100` in the sample data) between the current 4th and 5th fields

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk -F'=' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} NF==5 {$6=$5;$5=100} 1' file.txt
domain=server=hgdndh=0=100=value
domain=server=mds-hnfgd=0=200=value
domain=server=fjghgn=0=100=value
domain=server=skrufh=0=100=value
domain=server=kfhgnvb=0=100=value
domain=server=jghfnf=0=100=value
domain=server=fhf-ejeu-fkgj=0=100=value
domain=server=fhdnd=0=300=value
```

Replacing the hardcoded `100` with a variable reference:

```
$ newvalue=100
$ awk -v newv="${newvalue}" -F'=' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} NF==5 {$6=$5;$5=newv} 1' file.txt
domain=server=hgdndh=0=100=value
domain=server=mds-hnfgd=0=200=value
domain=server=fjghgn=0=100=value
domain=server=skrufh=0=100=value
domain=server=kfhgnvb=0=100=value
domain=server=jghfnf=0=100=value
domain=server=fhf-ejeu-fkgj=0=100=value
domain=server=fhdnd=0=300=value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with one invocation of `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS = OFS = "="}
  (NF == 5){print $1, $2, $3, $4, "100", $5}
  (NF == 6){print}
' file.txt
```